# Using WriteProcessMemory() in C++ with Multilevel Pointers and Offsets?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, pointers

One of the parameters for `WriteProcessMemory()` obviously asks for a pointer to the base address. But what if it is a multilevel pointer?  For example, let's say I had to find a pointer 3 times to finally get the static address and the first offset was 0, the second was 57 and the third was 268.  Now if I wanted to write to that exact location, how would I include the offsets into the `WriteProcessMemory()` function and do I have to include all three offsets or only the last one that led me to the static address? To clarify things, I am basically practicing manipulating memory on a first person shooter game on PC. My goal isn't really to make hacks or anything. I just wanted to practice writing memory into a process. (For example, I would try to write new values into the 'health' address or the 'ammo' address.) And I just mainly want to know how to account for the offsets in a multilevel pointer.

Comment: Just note: [`ReadProcessMemory` and `WriteProcessMemory` are not IPC mechanisms](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/01/17/513779.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

An address is an address.  It doesn't matter if you got to it with a multi-level pointer (a pointer to a pointer to a pointer).

The base address is the address you are going to write to.  What ever address your multi-level pointer is pointing to, goes in that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

WriteProcessMemory places absolute data into memory. If you want to write a multi-level structure into memory e.g. having pointers in the elements, then you need to write the pointer values based on the remote `lpBaseAddress` and the amount of data you're writing, and you need to write the data that is being placed in memory.

If there are pointers in the structure you're writing from, then unless you rewrite them to be part of the destination data that you're writing, then they will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "include" the offsets in a call to WriteProcessMemory() to walk a chain of pointers.  A multilevel pointer or pointer chain is a pointer that points to a pointer that points to a pointer.  In most cases there are relative offsets that must be added after each pointer is de referenced.

WriteProcessMemory just writes to a single address, it is singular in purpose.

But you must de-reference each pointer and add the offset.  To do this, you must use ReadProcessMemory.  You can use this function to walk the pointer chain, it will dereference each pointer and add the offset correctly:

```cs
uintptr_t FindDMAAddy(HANDLE hProc, uintptr_t ptr, std::vector<unsigned int> offsets)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < offsets.size(); ++i)
    {
        ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (BYTE*)ptr, &ptr, sizeof(ptr), 0);
        ptr += offsets[i];
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

An example of calling the function looks like:

```
uintptr_t ammoAddr = FindDMAAddy(hProcess, dynamicPtrBaseAddr, { 0x374, 0x14, 0x0 });
```

The result of this function will be the address of the variable you want to read or write.  All that's left to do is a subsequent call to ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory depending what you want to do.